# Variable value doesn't change when assigned inside a function

Tags: javascript, json

I wrote an image slideshow with HTML and JS for use in the Lively Wallpaper app.

The app allows customization. Properties are stored in LivelyProperties.json file with input type (slider, textbox etc.).

The properties are accessed by declaring : `function livelyPropertyListener(name, val){}` in the code of the html.

I have a slider in the **.json** file which appears in a menu inside the app.
Adjusting the slider sets the text to a number in a `<div>` via **.innerHTML** and it works fine, but the variable `transitionDuration` maintains the old value.

`anime` is an animation function from the **anime.js** library

JS is internal and no errors are reported when opening **.html** in Firefox.

```
        var textEl = document.querySelector(".text");
        var transitionDuration = 3000;
        var imageInterval = 5000;

        function livelyPropertyListener(name, val) //I assume this function is recognized when the .html file is parsed in the app
        {
            if(name =="transitionDuration")
            {
              transitionDuration = val; //transitionDuration stays 3000 (the value in the beginning of the code)
              textEl.innerHTML = val; //this works and the text updates as the slider is moved (due to app limitations file needs to be reloaded for it to updated, but that's fine)
            }
        }

        var ScaleEasingFunc = 'easeInQuad';

        anime({
          targets: '.transition',
          opacity:0,
          direction: 'alternate',
          loop: true,
          easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
          delay: imageInterval/2,
          endDelay: imageInterval/2,
          duration: transitionDuration,
          loopBegin: function(anim) {
            changeImage();
          },
        });

        anime({
            targets: '.scale',
            scale:1.1,
            translateX: screen.width*-1/100,
            translateY: screen.width*1/100,
            direction: 'alternate',
            loop: true,
            easing: ScaleEasingFunc,
            duration: imageInterval + 2*transitionDuration,
        });
</script>
```

Comment: changing the value of `transitionDuration` wont change the value of `duration`

Comment: How do you know that the value of `transitionDuration` isn't changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the order of events:

1. `var transitionDuration = 3000;` assigns a value to `transitionDuration`
2. `function livelyPropertyListener` defines a function
3. `anime({...})` reads the current value of `transitionDuration`, assigns it to a property of an object, and passes that object to the `anime` function
4. You call `livelyPropertyListener` and change the value of `transitionDuration`

Step 4 doesn't travel back in time so that `transitionDuration` had the new value **before** it was read at step 3.

If you want to change what the `anime` function is doing after it has been initilised, then it needs to return a value which provides an API which will let you update the duration.