# Calling Global Variables in a Function?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to JavaScript, so I'm trying to understand why
my JavaScript code below works. I have a text field with a button and I just want to check if the user input is correct or not. I'm a bit confused as to why I would get no output if I defined my 'response' variable on the line after where I defined my 'answer' variable.

Could someone please help me understand why the function wouldn't be able to compare two global variables? Or does it have to do with how 'onclick' works?

```html
   <h3>How many states are in the United States of America?</h3>

    <!--Add text field and submit button-->
    <input type="text" id="textbox" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Answer...">
    <button type="button" onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit</button>

    <!--Add division for answer pop up display-->
    <div id="answer2"></div>

    <script>
        // Set correct answer
        var answer = 50;

        function checkAnswer() {
            // Get input value
            var response = document.getElementById('textbox').value;

            // Compare input with correct answer and change division text
            if (response == answer) {
                answer2.innerHTML = "Correct!";
            }

            // Input provided but not correct answer, change division text
            else if (response.length != 0) {
                answer2.innerHTML = "Incorrect!";
            }
        }
     </script>
```

Comment: By *no answer* what do you mean? Do you get any errors? It's probably because DOM isn't created yer and you are getting errors in the console.

Comment: It's generally easier for people to understand a question if you show the code you have a problem and not just show working code with a description of how to break it.

Comment: If you do `var response = document.getElementById('textbox').value;` on a "global" (ie outside the function) level, it is executed only once, when the site is initially loaded (and `response` is initialized to an empty string). After that `response` never changes anymore, regardless of what you enter into the input box, because there is no code running anymore that looks at `getElementById('textbox').value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable value doesn't change when assigned inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920148/variable-value-doesnt-change-when-assigned-inside-a-function)

Comment: To be clear, you can *define* the variable right underneath answer, but if you *assign* the value there, it will be static, before the user has done any input. If you define the variable globally, and then assign it inside the function, it will still work. 
(PS, I would keep the variable inside of the function anyway. Then again, a step further for multiple answers/questions other data structures would be better, or a data attribute on the question, but that is out of scope :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how time works.

If you change the code as you describe then:

1. You set `answer` to `50`
2. You read the value of the input (`""`) and assign it to `response`
3. The user types something into the input
4. The user clicks the button
5. The `checkAnswer` function is called
6. `response` (`""`) is compared to `answer` (`50`).

If you move step 2 inside the `checkAnswer` function (as per the code you have that works) then you read the value after the user has changed it.

Comment: But... the OP sets `response` in the `checkAnswer` function...

Comment: @HereticMonkey — That's why I said "If you change the code as you describe" in reference to the second paragraph of the question which says "why I would get no output if I defined my 'response' variable on the line after where I defined my 'answer' variable"

Comment: Ah, so the code in the question is just reference... got ya :). Seems like we should have a dupe for this somewhere though.

Comment: Probably, but I couldn't think of any good search terms to track one down.

Comment: It was even one you answered :)